# How can i send a mail to specific user when workflow state is changed or changed to particular state?

Tags: rules, workflows

I want to send a mail when workflow state will change from creation to pending,from pending to approval and from approval to published. How can i achieve this. I have tried with rules but it can't be done using same.
I am using drupal 7.34 .

Comment: I have workaround with rules and i found it helpful, But more preferred way in my case is to write hook for sending an email according to states.

Comment: Please include an export of your rule that you tried to use (if if it doesn't work yet). That should help to better understand your question. Also, why not post an answer yourself with the "workaround" you already have?

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved with the help of [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.

> The Rules module allows site administrators to define conditionally executed actions based on occurring events (known as reactive or ECA rules). It's a replacement with more features for the trigger module in core and the successor of the Drupal 5 workflow-ng module.
>   *Example use cases*
>
> Build flexible content publishing workflows changes
>       Send customized mails to notify your users about important
>       Create custom redirections, system messages, breadcrumbs, ...
>       Build an eCommerce store using Drupal Commerce
>
> And many more...

Check [Tutorial: editorial workflow with rules](https://www.drupal.org/node/1027546), which has good documentation on the how to's.

Comment: I have  used this with all the perspectives. But it is not working as i need it.

Comment: Can you edit the question and mention what have you tried and what is not working?